# css overlay with a div without overlay

Tags: css, overlay

I have a panel with css class for overlay, which contains a div which should be NOT transparent

```
<asp:panel id="panelOverlay" runat="server" class="Overlay" visible="false">
        <asp:panel id="panelPopUpPanel" runat="server" class="PopUpPanel" visible="false">
            <asp:panel id="panelPopUpTitle" runat="server" style="width: 100%; height: 20px; text-align: right; ">
                <asp:imagebutton id="cmdClosePopUp" runat="server" imageurl="~/pict/graphics/delete.png"></asp:imagebutton>
            </asp:panel>
        <div class="noOverlay">
            <h4>This is the PopUp Window</h4>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="codice"></asp:Label>
        </div>                               
        <div>&nbsp;</div>
        </asp:panel>
    </asp:panel>
```

I have this css class

```
.Overlay { 
          position:fixed; 
          top:0px; 
          bottom:0px; 
          left:0px; 
          right:0px; 
          overflow:hidden; 
          padding:0; 
          margin:0; 
          background-color:#000;  
          filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
          opacity:0.5; 
          z-index:1000;
        }

    .noOverlay { 
      background-color:#ffffff;  
      filter:alpha(opacity=100); 
      opacity:1; 
    }
```

I can't set up the .noOverlay css to make it work
Thank you

Comment: Define the size of the `.Overlay`? Like `width: 100%; height: 100%;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.noOverlay` IS NOT transparent, but its parent container is which causes `.noOverlay` to appear as if it were also transparent.

Use `rgba` instead, which allows you to set the background's color and the background's transparency for that specific element only:

```css
body {background:green}

.demoBox {
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
.Overlay {
  /* The last argument is the transparency from 0 to 1 */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color:#fff;
}
.noOverlay {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="demoBox Overlay">
  I am a transparent div

  <div class="demoBox noOverlay">I am not a transparent div</div>
</div>
```

As you'll see here, the `.noOverlay` is contained within the `.Overlay` div, however, only the `.Overlay` is transparent.